# Get Tag from id => javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am curious if it is possible to get tag equivalent to jquery's $('tag_name') by just having an id at hand?
For example:

```
    var some_id = document.getElementById('my_Id');
    //and then do something like
    var get_tag = some_id.its_tag;
```

Is something like this possible?

I know we can get all tags into one place, like list, and then loop through that list and check each id, but curious if there is something that can be done elegantly?

Thanks!

Alternative is known, but would be great if original question actually has some answer too.

```
    var some_id = document.getElementById('my_Id');
    //and then do something like
    var get_tag = some_id.its_tag;
```

Comment: `someElement.tagName` gets the upper-case version of the tag

Comment: You can check [here (HTMLElement)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) and [here (Element)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) for more DOM properties etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var some_id = document.getElementById('my_Id');
var tag = some_id.tagName;
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the problem, consider leaving a comment in the answer about why this solves the OP's problem

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen ok i will be take care next time.Thanks for advising.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) property (it represents the tag name in uppercase):

```js
var some_element = document.getElementById('my_Id');

console.log(some_element.tagName); // => P
```

```html
<p id="my_Id">Hello</p>
```